# python logging print traceback only in debug

Tags: python, logging

I am currently loading the python logger like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger("myprogram")
```

and using it e. g. like this:

```
[...]
except FileNotFoundError:
    log.exception("could not open configuration file")
    sys.exit(1)
```

However, this will always print the traceback along with the error message:

```
ERROR:myprogram:could not open configuration file
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'not/existing/file.yml'
```

I do not want the traceback in the normal error output. Instead it should only print my error message and the exception info ("No such file...").

What is the recommended way of showing the traceback only when the loglevel is set to `logging.DEBUG`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a combination of `exc_info` and [`.getEffectiveLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel):

```
try:
    ...
except FileNotFoundError as ex:
   logger.error(ex, exc_info=log.getEffectiveLevel() == logging.DEBUG)
```

This way, the exception itself (`FileNotFoundError`) is always logged, but the stacktrace will only be logged if log level is debug.

Comment: I ended up defining a helper function like this: `def err(*args, **kwargs): log.error(*args, exc_info=log.getEffectiveLevel() == logging.DEBUG, **kwargs)`, does exactly what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Log the exception at `DEBUG` level instead and set `exc_info=True`. `logger.exception()` is essentially a `logger.error(..., exc_info=True)` call, but you can log exception tracebacks at any level:

```
log.debug("could not open configuration file", exc_info=True)
```

It's the `exc_info` option that's important; from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug):

> If `exc_info` does not evaluate as false, it causes exception information to be added to the logging message. If an exception tuple (in the format returned by `sys.exc_info()`) or an exception instance is provided, it is used; otherwise, `sys.exc_info()` is called to get the exception information.

You perhaps want to use printing (to stdout or stderr) to communicate with the end-user:

```
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    log.debug("could not open configuration file", exc_info=True)
    print("Could not open configuration file:", e.strerror, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

I included the [system error message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError.strerror) in the print output without the `FileNotFoundError(...)` representation.

If you use a command-line argument parser like `argparse` or `click`, then do use their user feedback API (which usually includes exiting too).

You *can* make the logging module produce user-level messages too, but if you want a single logger call to produce debug-friendly tracebacks in a file and user-friendly output on a console, you'd have to configure separate handlers for these use-cases with the console handler using a custom [`Formatter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) to [override the `formatException()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException) to alter how exceptions are shown. It's just much easier and clearer to separate logging and end-user communication.

Comment: ok, I was under the wrong impression that the logging module would take exactly this burden off the programmer. I indeed use argparse, which I should use here for handling this particualr error, but I have more places in the program where I need this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SebastianStark: logging can, sort-of, take care of this, but then you'd have to configure an extra handler that shows only end-user messages, and use a custom `Formatter` subclass to alter how exception information is included in the output. I usually just use what I outlined in my answer instead.

Comment: In this case it is a daemon and I want everything always in the log. Although I think what you propose is the right way usually, I prefer something simpler for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly use `logging.debug` plus traceback:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Unhandled exception: %s", e)
    logger.debug("Traceback: %s", traceback.format_exc())
```

Edit: `logger.debug("", exc_info=True)` can be used instead of `logger.debug("Traceback: %s", traceback.format_exc())`.